# how to use an app as a module in another app iOS swift

Tags: swift, frameworks, xcode11

I build an app1 and I need to use that app in second app as a module with storyboards. How can I do this and what is the best approach.  The developer of second app can change in the code and design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly I am just a learn myself but based on little knowledge that I have,I would suggest you to change. `target` -> `add capabilities` of the app, select `app groups` in the capability.
Next you need to use `frameworks` to have a common access.

Hope this helps :)